# Getting the list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using linq code parsing XML file.This is my code.I want bind detail and image are list.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notchs));
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(dataInXmlFile);
Notchs notchs = (Notchs)serializer.Deserialize(xmlDoc.CreateReader());

var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
            select new Notch
            {
                name = (string)l.Attribute("name").Value,
                Titles = l.Element("Details").Elements("detail")
                           .Select(s => s.Attribute("games").ToString())
                           .ToList(),

                Image = l.Element("Details").Elements("detail").Elements("event_image").Elements("image")
                         .Select(x => x.Attribute("url").ToString()).ToList()
            };

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.name);
    foreach (var detail in result.Titles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(detail);
    }
}
NotchsList.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

This is i am using XML file and i want to get name and games with image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <Peoples>
  <Person name="Raja">
   <Details>
    <detail games="Cricket">
      <event_image>
        <image  url="http://Cricket.jpeg"/>
      <event_image>
    </detail>
    <detail games="Foot Ball">
     <event_image>
       <image  url="http://FootBall.jpeg"/>
     <event_image>
    </detail>
    <detail games="Volley Ball">
     <event_image>
      <image  url="http://.Volley.jpeg3"/>
     <event_image>
    </detail>
   </Details>
  </Person>
  <Person name="Rama">
    <Details>
     <detail games="Chess">
      <event_image>
        <image  url="http://Chess.jpeg"/1>
      <event_image>
     </detail>
     <detail games="Table Tennis">
      <event_image>
       <image  url="http://TTennis.jpeg"/>
      <event_image>
     </detail>
     <detail games="Carrom">
      <event_image>
       <image  url="http://Carrom.jpeg"/>
      <event_image>
     </detail>
   </Details>
  </Person>
 </Peoples>
</root>
```

My Code like

```
public class Notch
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("games")]
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("url")]
    public List<string> Image { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Notchs
{
    [XmlArray("Peoples")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Person")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Details")]
    public ObservableCollection<Notch> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

My xaml file

```
  <ListBox x:Name="NotchsList" 
        SelectionChanged="NotchsList_SelectionChanged"   Margin="0,-5.25,22,0"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="768" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Height="160"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <StackPanel Background="#eb2427" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="34" FontWeight="Bold"  FontStyle="Normal" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                Text="{Binding name}"
                                   />               
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                             <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="32" Foreground="#a7a9ac"
                                Text="{Binding games}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>     

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Grid.Row="1"  Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="top" />
                        </StackPanel>           
                </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I got output like

Raja

```
  System.collection.generic.list'1[System.String]

  System.collection.generic.list'1[System.String]
```

Rama

```
  System.collection.generic.list'1[System.String]

  System.collection.generic.list'1[System.String]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already mentioned your XML has a few typos. After fixing that and removing the unused `XmlSerializer` your query produces a valid `IEnumerable<Notch>`. Everything works as expected.

But I strongly doubt that you want to have the full attributes in your `Titles` list. Actually you want to have their values. So you have to write `Attribute(...).Value` and omit `ToString()`:

```
var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
            select new Notch
            {
                name = (string)l.Attribute("name").Value,
                Titles = l.Element("Details").Elements("detail")
                          .Select(s => s.Attribute("games").Value)
                          .ToList(),

                Image = l.Element("Details").Elements("detail")
                         .Elements("event_image").Elements("image")
                         .Select(x => x.Attribute("url").Value).ToList()
            };

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.name);
    foreach (var detail in result.Titles.Zip(result.Image, (st, si) => string.Format("{0} {1}", st, si)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(detail);
    }
}
```

Note that I used the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method to combine related titles and image urls. But this is only for a better output. The data is already correct. This is the output:

```
Raja
Cricket http://Cricket.jpeg
Foot Ball http://FootBall.jpeg
Volley Ball http://.Volley.jpeg3
Rama
Chess http://Chess.jpeg
Table Tennis http://TTennis.jpeg
Carrom http://Carrom.jpeg
```

However your data will not show up in your listbox. You bind to `games` instead of `Titles` and you use `TextBlock` to show a list which produces the output you mentioned. It should also be a `ListBox`. Here is a "slightly" simplified but working version:

```
<ListBox x:Name="NotchsList">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}" Width="200" />
          <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Image}" Width="200" />
        </StackPanel>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: output.png]

Comment: hi i hope your answer i got same thing above your answer but i need images not like path

Comment: hi i want scroll below the image with title.you are getting values to list box.i dont want bind this type i want name below image want scroll with title.so please tel me any idea...,

Comment: @user123: You need a [listbox with horizontal layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292516/wpf-listbox-that-lays-out-its-items-horizontally). Also you must actually [download the images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659574/synchronously-download-an-image-from-url).

Answer (score 3):

you need to change

```
s.Attribute("games").ToString()
x.Attribute("url").ToString()
```

to:

```
s.Attribute("games").Value.ToString()
x.Attribute("url").Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Hi thanks to replay i tried this but i got error like             1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I don't really understand what each object is so its hard to tell. What is NotchsList.ItemsSource? it's most likely this that is causing the problem. changing it to "var source = query.ToList()" works fine for me. Also, the Deserialize isn't required to get what you want. It's all a little messy to be honest.

Comment: Hi doiley thanks to your replay i hope ur answer. am new for linq to xml.so please tell me what i want to write?

Comment: take a look at the other answers, they all provide more info on what you should be doing. I'm not going to just write the same things they have. Hope i've helped.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing your XML tag endings - closing all  event_image tags and remove the "1" if the chess image as below and removing line 1 and 3 of your code, and the last line - the serializer and call to it which are not used. I got the following output:

```
Raja
games="Cricket"
games="Foot Ball"
games="Volley Ball"
Rama
games="Chess"
games="Table Tennis"
games="Carrom"
```

--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Peoples>
    <Person name="Raja">
      <Details>
        <detail games="Cricket">
          <event_image>
            <image  url="http://Cricket.jpeg"/>
          </event_image>
        </detail>
        <detail games="Foot Ball">
          <event_image>
            <image  url="http://FootBall.jpeg"/>
          </event_image>
        </detail>
        <detail games="Volley Ball">
          <event_image>
            <image  url="http://.Volley.jpeg3"/>
          </event_image>
        </detail>
      </Details>
    </Person>
    <Person name="Rama">
      <Details>
        <detail games="Chess">
          <event_image>
            <image  url="http://Chess.jpeg"/>
          </event_image>
        </detail>
        <detail games="Table Tennis">
          <event_image>
            <image  url="http://TTennis.jpeg"/>
          </event_image>
        </detail>
        <detail games="Carrom">
          <event_image>
            <image  url="http://Carrom.jpeg"/>
          </event_image>
        </detail>
      </Details>
    </Person>
  </Peoples>
</root>
```

This is produced using your code Copy-pasted but I **removed** the following lines:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notchs)); //first line
Notchs notchs = (Notchs)serializer.Deserialize(xmlDoc.CreateReader()); //third line
NotchsList.ItemsSource = query.ToList(); //last line in your code snippet
```

Comment: @user123: He tried your code - fix the malformed xml and remove the unused serializer. It's your code that produces this result.

Comment: As @pescolino said. I've also went ahead and explicitly listed the lines I removed to get it to work.
 P.S. thanks pescolino for a more timely response.

Comment: yes you are telling correct but where can you show the output? NotchList is the listbox x:Name.i through the output via listbox

Comment: @Infinite Possiblities first thing i want bind games with images and second thing is lists want horizontal scroll view like cricket below cricket image,football below football image.