# Why this simple code which loads an image from a server doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am playing with mage source in wpf and tried this simple test to see if I can get any lucky:

```
 var test = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://thenotebook.org/sites/default/files/fallCartoon.jpg"));
```

when looking at test in debug window, all of its properties are set to null and hence it doesn't seem that it loaded the image. why?

Comment: Can you open that image in your browser with the same URI?  And what happens if you create the URI separately and then feed it into the Bitmap?

Comment: yes I can. I did this to make sure that it is a valid uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapImage loads network data asynchronously. Which means that it returns right away while starting the download in the background. So there may be nothing wrong with your code. Check the [`IsDownloading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.isdownloading%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Subscribe to the [`DownloadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`DownloadFailed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadfailed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events.

Sync version according to our comments:

```
var bytes = new WebClient().DownloadData("https://thenotebook.org/sites/default/files/fallCartoon.jpg");
var test = new BitmapImage();
test.BeginInit();
test.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes);
test.EndInit();
Console.WriteLine(test.PixelWidth);
Console.WriteLine(test.PixelHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that I make is sync? I tried chacheoption and set it to None, but no difference

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It's been asked already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659574/synchronously-download-an-image-from-url . I would download the file with a WebClient and initialize the bitmap from a memory stream. So you don't need to save a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Following fejesjoco's advice:

```
public static BitmapImage ImageFromUriSync(string uri)
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] data = client.DownloadData(uri);

        using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            img.BeginInit();
            img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            img.StreamSource = stream;
            img.EndInit();

            return img;
        }
    }
}
```